# How to find the reason for "Java Swing Application not exit after close", via Netbeans IDE debug mode?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, netbeans, jdialog

A JDialog (singleton object) invoked from a JInternalframe (which is in JFrame) several times for data entry.
After JFrame get closed, still the application not get end. (Able to see the running status in the netbeans ide).
**After correcting the owner component set to the JDialog (initially new JDialog()) it got resolved (So much of time spent on Trial and error method to resolved this problem).**
But before resolving this issue, in debug mode i saw below given 5 line items in the debug tab of the netbeans ide

- 'AWT-EventQueue-0' running
- 'AWT-Shutdown' running
- 'AWT-Windows' running
- 'D3D Screen Updater' running
- 'HSQLDB timer @4564654f0' running

Using the above details, did i have a chance to find the problem quickly in debug mode (which was resolved) **(or)** else any method is there to find **(or)** need to write code properly :)?

**Another form of Question Explanation:**

JDialog invoked from the JInternalframe. Invoked repeatedly in the form of setvisible(true), ..false, ..true, ...false like that. After JInternalframe(+JFrame) close, still the program running. The reason is JDialog not attached with JInternalframe/JFrame using JDialog(**owner**,model). Previously it was simply JDialog(). I found (using Trial and Error method) and fixed the problem that the owner not set to the JDialog. Is it possible to find this problem using the Netbeans IDE debug mode?

Comment: Did you use `JFrameVariableName.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`?

Comment: JInternalframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); will happen based on a validation return boolean value. But this issue happened after getting the true also. (JInternalframe got closed properly and still application running)

Comment: JDialog added as an  enhancement to the application. Only the application not behaved properly after this addition. So did the Trial and error method on the newly added JDialog :)

Answer (score 0):

The "HSQLDB timer" entry shows you have connected to a database. Before shutting down your app, you must execute the SQL statement "SHUTDOWN" on the database to close it properly. Doing this will stop the "HSQLDB timer" thread.

Comment: Thanks @fredt. May be my poor English writing not explaining the question to you properly. I have added some more explanation to the question. See **Another form of Question Explanation:**

Comment: And also please refer the 3rd comment of the question.